# Hash Map implementation in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

So I am trying to implement `dict` from scratch considering collision ,too which i handled through the separate chaining. I have added some key value pairs from the `.csv` file to count most occurring word. But I am struggling to add up values since it stores the same key several times in the same index in spite of handling this(see the code `hash_table[word] += 1`.....). I have tried debugging still could not pinpoint the issue.

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max = 50
        self.array = [[] for item in range(self.max)]

    
    def hash(self, key):
        hash_values = 0
        if len(key) == 1:
            hash_values = ord(key)
        else:
            for char in key:
                hash_values += ord(char)
        
        return hash_values % 50

    
    def __setitem__(self, key, values):
        hash = self.hash(key)
        for idx, item in enumerate(self.array[hash]):
            if len(item) == 2 and item[0] == key:
                self.array[hash][idx][1] =+ 1
                break
        self.array[hash].append([key, values])

    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        h = self.hash(key)
        for idx, item in enumerate(self.array[h]):
            if item[0] == key:
                return item[1]
              

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.array}"

hash_table = HashMap()

word_dict = []
with open("poem.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            word = word.replace('\n','')
            if hash_table[word]:
                hash_table[word] += 1
                break
            hash_table[word] = 1
```

.csv:

```
Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,
And sorry I could not travel both
And be one traveler, long I stood
And looked down one as far as I could
To where it bent in the undergrowth;

and

Then took the other, as just as fair,
And having perhaps the better claim,
Because it was grassy and wanted wear;
Though as for that the passing there
Had worn them really about the same,
```

Output:

```
[[['And', 1], ['sorry', 1], ['And', 2], ['And', 2], ['bent', 1], ['', 1], ['', 2], ['And', 2]], [], [], [], [['travel', 1], ['both', 1], ['just', 1], ['worn', 1]], [['them', 1]], [], [['and', 1]], [], [], [['wood,', 1], ['could', 1]], [], [['roads', 1], ['not', 1], ['as', 1], ['as', 2], ['as', 2]]......]
```

As you noticed, `HashMap` stored identical keys in the same index several time.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.  First, in `__setitem__`, you have  `=+ 1`.  What that says is "set the value of this item to +1".  You want `+= 1`.  C has both, Python only has the one.

Second, in `__setitem__`, if you FIND the item, you modify the entry, then you `break` out of the loop, which then appends ANOTHER item to the list.  You should `return`, not `break`.

With those two fixes, your code works for me.